# Wi-Fi stops working after some period of time?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-4

Am using raspberry pi 4 2GB with Raspbian OS for the last 3.5 months. everything was going well. From last week Wi-Fi is not get connecting. my pi can able to detect Wi-Fi but it's not connecting with the network. But when I use an external Wi-Fi dongle both the internal and external Wi-Fi is getting connected. But the internal Wi-Fi connection is very very slow compared to its previous performance. I inquired about this with my friends who are all using raspberry pi 4 everyone's pi is working fine, but one guy is having the same issue. While using 3b+ also met with this same issue.

I want to understand why it not and what's the problem, if we can solve the problem means what will be the solution. am having around 10 raspberry pi 4 but only on one raspberry pi am having the issue. if the internal Wi-Fi module is faulted means how it can able to connect when I put an external dongle. it kind of confusing.

And one more thing if its off topic means suggest to me where I need to post this issue

Comment: First step: Try resetting your wifi access point.

Comment: also, I'd try a fresh install of Raspbian latest image (January 11th 2021) - and if that's OK, then apt upgrade it and see if it still works ... I'm assuming you keep your pi upgraded to the latest version

Comment: Have you tried restoring from your backup?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a power issue - do you have anything else plugged into the Pi?

The 3B+ was prone to 'iffy' WiFi with cheap adapters but using the 'official' one normally sorted it.

Other things:

- I would check the country code is set correctly as well on both your AP and Pi
- It's possible you are using a very popular channel - fix the working channel on the AP
- Is this Pi out of range / near DECT phones or a microwave or Bluetooth or Zigbee devices?

Answer (score -1):

Could just be a damaged component.

I have a mac that does the same thing soon after a close relative said they knew what they were doing whilst recklessly taking out the Hard Drive.